# pygame.display.update() not detecting new changes

Tags: python, pygame

so i've changed the window color to a white color, unfortunately its not updating, [it also returns an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAHBd.png)

code:

```
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display = pygame.display.set_caption('PyGame Test')
WHITE = (255,255,255)
def main():
  run = True
  while run:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              run = False

      WIN.fill(WHITE)
      pygame.display.update()
      
  pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the caption of the window, you need to type `pygame.display.set_caption("Caption")`. In your code, I see that you typed `pygame.display = pygame.display.set_caption('PyGame Test')`, which results in an `AttributeError` because `pygame.display.set_caption()` returns `None`, meaning you set `pygame.display` to `None`. So if you replace that line with `pygame.display.set_caption('PyGame Test')`, it will work.

## Full code:

```
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('PyGame Test')
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        WIN.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For more info, check [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-pygame-window/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20pygame%20uses%20%E2%80%9CPygame,set%20icon%20of%20our%20window.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to initialize the display module. Try pygame.init()

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init

Comment: hm, didnt work, where exactly do i need to put it?